# Induced homomorphism on cohomology by fibration

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fibration

Let $\pi:E \to M$ be a fibration, where $M$ is simply connected. How can I show that $\pi^{*}:H^{*}(M) \to H^{*}(E)$ is injective?

This fact was used in the proof of proposition 18.13 in Bott and Tu, but I don't know why this is true. I've also tried looking up some sources but haven't seen this result stated elsewhere. On a side note, I realized that if there is a section $s:M \to E$ then $\pi^{*}$ will be injective but I believe fibrations don't generally have sections(?). Other than this remark I don't have any ideas how to show this.

I would be grateful if someone can show me a proof of why this is correct

Comment: This is false. Take $\pi$ to be the Hopf fibration.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thank you for the nice counterexample. However, I realized I have made a mistake while typing the question: I meant $\Omega^*$ by $H^*$. I have asked the right version of the question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875716/induced-homomorphism-on-cohomology-by-fibration-take-2. Can you also please help me with my original intended question too?