# Induced homomorphism on cohomology by fibration (take 2)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fibration

Let $\pi: E \to M$ be a fibration of smooth manifolds, where $M$ is simply connected. How can I show that $\pi^*:\Omega^*(M) \to \Omega^*(E)$ is injective?

This fact was used in the proof of proposition 18.13 in Bott and Tu, but I don't know why this is true. I've also tried looking up some sources but haven't seen this result stated elsewhere. On a side note, I realized that if there is a section $s:M \to E$, $\pi^*$ will be injective but I believe fibrations don't generally have sections(?).

Please note that I have asked the same question at [Induced homomorphism on cohomology by fibration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875637/induced-homomorphism-on-cohomology-by-fibration) but sadly had made a mistake in mistyping $\Omega^*$ as $H^*$. Since MikeMiller has provided a nice counterexample for that problem it seems appropriate for me ask the right version of my question in another topic.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by $\Omega^*(M)$? Just the de Rham cochain complex? Then the statement that $\pi^*$ is injective is the same as the statement as that $\pi$ is a submersion.

Comment: ...and $\pi$ must be a submersion since the dimension of $E$ must be greater or equal than $M$, or else by Sard's theorem $E \to M$ will not be surjective. Right? Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's not quite it, since certainly many surjective maps are not submersions. (There are surjective maps from the sphere to the torus, eg, but nos ubmersions.) You want to use the local product structure of the fibration.

Comment: Yes my previous comment was wrong. Can you please elaborate on the 'local product structure of the fibration'? I know the fibers of a fibration are all homotopy equivalent, and the fiber of a contractible open set is homotopy equivalent to the trivial bundle, but since that is only a homotopy equivalence and not a diffeomorphism we cannot conclude $\pi$ is a submersion by looking at the corresponding trivial bundle (In fact if such is possible then we can extract a section and be done already)

Comment: I guess I assumed that when you/Bott-Tu said fibration here, you meant smooth fiber bundle. I don't understand why it would be true for an arbitrary fibration. Can you point to where in the proof you see this used?

Comment: @MikeMiller It is used in P.247, in the proof of Proposition 18.13. The authors left it as a 'remark' below the statement of the proposition, but then later used it in the proof of the proposition in P.248 Line 8.